# Is it possible to hava two seperate middlewares for frontend and backend in laravel?

Tags: laravel

I have a platform created with laravel 5.4.I did the authentification process for the backend and everything is working fine.For my front pages i also to want them to be accessed when the user is only logged (client).Do i have to redirect by role or can i have seperate authentification for each side ?

Answer (score 0):

In general, this is achieved defining some type of `roles` in your application, sort of `user` or `admin`. See official docs regarding [authorization](https://laravel.com/docs/authorization).

Also, check [this article](https://geekytomato.com/laravel-protect-admin-routes/), as it does exactly what you want in a simple but effective way :)

Comment: yes thank you.I did the redirection depending on the role of the logged user